# Looping through objects with names

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to loop through data with node.js. I don't know how to proceed it without returning `undefined` errors.

**JSON**

```
{
  "task": {
    "task-1": {
      "job": "Engineer"
    },
    "task-2": {
      "job": "Developer"
    }
  }
}
```

What I've attempted to do

```
var jobs = {
  "task": {
    "task-1": {
      "job": "Engineer"
    },
    "task-2": {
      "job": "Developer"
    }
  }
};

for (var i in jobs) {
  console.log(jobs[i].job);
}
```

I can't seem to get it working.

**Update**

So you guys are saying that I should do something like this?

```
for (var i in jobs.task) {
  console.log(jobs.task[i].job);
}
```

Comment: You need to loop over `jobs.task`

Comment: so I'll be looping `for (var i in jobs.task)`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. `jobs` is a JavaScript object. Also you already seem to know how to iterate over an object since `jobs` is an object.

Comment: See also [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: How do I get the name of that object e.g `task-1`, `task-2`? Whenever I do `jobs.task[i]` it prints out the whole object, not just the name.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var jobs = {
  "task": {
    "task-1": {
      "job": "Engineer"
    },
    "task-2": {
      "job": "Developer"
    }
  }
};

for (let task in jobs) {
  for (let taskNumber in jobs[task]) {
    console.log('Job: ', jobs[task][taskNumber].job)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll test this out. :)

Comment: It would probably make more sense to iterate over `jobs.task`.

Comment: This looks terrible and is bad practice. Downvote.